# Find tables from sql

Tags: python

Is there a way to find tables by just looking at sql . may be using python or other tools.

eg

```
 SELECT *
          FROM TABLEA TFR
          JOIN TABLEB TR
            ON (TFR.DIMENSIONID = TR.DIMENSIONID)
         WHERE TFR.DAYCD >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02/18/2019', 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'YYYYMMDD')
           AND TFR.DAYCD <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02/20/2019', 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'YYYYMMDD')
           AND TFR.DURATIONTYPEID IN ('1')
         GROUP BY TFR.DAYCD, TR.DIMENSION, TR.ORDERID
```

We would like to extract `TABLEA , TABLEB` from this.I have tried https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but it does not work.

Functions are in https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/examples/extract_table_names.py
Following is code

```
sql='''

SELECT *
          FROM TABLEA TFR
          JOIN TABLEB TR
            ON (TFR.DIMENSIONID = TR.DIMENSIONID)
         WHERE TFR.DAYCD >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02/18/2019', 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'YYYYMMDD')
           AND TFR.DAYCD <= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('02/20/2019', 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'YYYYMMDD')
           AND TFR.DURATIONTYPEID IN ('1')
         GROUP BY TFR.DAYCD, TR.DIMENSION, TR.ORDERID


'''
extract_tables(sql)
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Show the code.

Comment: Are you using mysql?